# AJAX CalendarExtender refresh update panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I've added a CalendarExtender to reset the dates of a datasource for a grid view.

Code -

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPTabs" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="tbMoveInDate" eventname="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbMoveInDate" Width="70px" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"/>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="tbMoveInDateCalendarExtender" runat="server" Format="MM/yyyy"
                        TargetControlID="tbMoveInDate" OnClientHidden="onCalendarHidden" OnClientShown="onCalendarShown" />

    <asp:GridView ID="gvMoveins" runat="server" .../>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

with the intention of forcing the update panel to update when the date is changed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger />
```

to get the effect I needed.